# New to OOP with python, need help updating a self.lifepoints within my __init__ function,

Tags: python, class, methods, init

I'm writing a program called battle bots that is pretty simple but I'm new to OOP with python so I'm struggling to get it to work well. My biggest issue is updating the life points within my **init** method. In the **init** I have self.lifepoints = 100 but when a 'bot' takes damage I need that number to update to the number equivalent to the damage. Here is the code, I could really use some advice

```
import random

class player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.lifepoints = 100

    def getStrength(self):
        self.strength = random.randint(1, 40)
        return self.strength
    
    def doDamage(self):
        self.damage = self.lifepoints - self.strength
        
        return self.damage
    
        

class botGame:
    
    bot1 = player()
    bot2 = player() 
    while True:

        print("Welcome to Battle Bots...")
        choice = input("Bot 1 it's your turn, press 'h' to Hit or 'q' to Quit: ")
        while True:
            print("Bot 1 life points: ", bot1.lifepoints, '\n', "Bot 2 life points: ", bot2.lifepoints)
            

            if choice == 'q':
                quit
            
            if choice == 'h':
                print("Bot 1's strength: ",bot1.getStrength())
                print("Bot 2's strength: ",bot2.getStrength())
                # if statement for .getstrength() for each bot
                if bot1.strength > bot2.strength:
                    print(bot1.doDamage())
                else:
                    print(bot2.doDamage())
                
                print("Bot 1 life points: ",bot1.lifepoints)
                print("Bot 2 life points: ",bot2.lifepoints)
                break
        while True:    
            print("Bot 2, your turn!")
            choice = input("Bot 1 it's your turn, press 'h' to Hit or 'q' to Quit: ")
                
            if choice == 'h':
                print("Bot 1's strength: ",bot1.getStrength())
                print("Bot 2's strength: ",bot2.getStrength())
                print(player.doDamage(bot1, bot2))
                print("Bot 1 life points: ",bot1.lifepoints)
                print("Bot 2 life points: ",bot2.lifepoints)

                if bot1.lifepoints > bot2.lifepoints:
                    print("Bot 1 Wins this round!", '\n'," Thanks for playing!", '\n', "Goodbye!")
                else:
                    print("Bot 2 Wins this round!", '\n'," Thanks for playing!", '\n', "Goodbye!")
                break
```

Comment: IMO, `botGame` looks more like a function than a class.

Comment: You could put somewhere in botGame `bot1.lifepoints -= damage`. Don't update it in the `__init__` function since you want to update it _after_ you created the instance.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly thank you I appreciate the feedback. I also realized I have a bigger issue that is calculating the damage taken from each of the bots points. So I need the damage to be the bot with the lower strength subtracted from the higher and the bot who had the lower strength takes that subtracted amount from their life points. But I'm not sure if I should compare the strengths in the player class or the botGame

Comment: `if bot1.strength > bot2.strength: bot2.lifepoints -= bot2.strength - bot1.strength` (I'm writing a single line for the comment). Note that the `doDamage` method is trying to inflict damage to self in the most literal way: to the bot that should be doing the damage and in function of it's own strength.

Comment: All that code should absolutely not be going in the body of `class botGame`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I can agree with that, but my understanding of OOP is quite minimal as you've most likely realized. how would I add bot1.strength > bot2.. into the body of class player when bot is not defined in that class?

Comment: bot1 and bot2 are different instances. So, you could compare strengths of bots the same way you would compare lengths of strings... you don't need/want a compare function as a class method. How would that method know who is the other bot?

Answer (score -1):

This is the final program I ended up using

```
import random

class player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.lifepoints = 100

    def getStrength(self):
        self.strength = random.randint(1, 40)
        
        return self.strength
    
    def doDamage(self, attack):
        self.attack = attack
        return self.attack
    
        
count = 0

class botGame:
    
    bot1 = player()
    bot2 = player() 
    
    print("Welcome to Battle Bots...")
    print("Bot 1 life points: ", bot1.lifepoints, '\n', "Bot 2 life points: ", bot2.lifepoints)
        
    choice = input("Bot 1 it's your turn, press 'h' to Hit or 'q' to Quit: ")
    while count < 2:
            
            

            if choice == 'q':
                quit
            
            if choice == 'h':
                print("Bot 1's strength: ",bot1.getStrength())
                print("Bot 2's strength: ",bot2.getStrength())
                # if statement for .getstrength() for each bot
                if bot1.strength > bot2.strength:
                    attack = bot1.strength - bot2.strength
                    bot2.lifepoints -= bot1.doDamage(attack)
                    print("Bot 2 takes", bot1.doDamage(attack),"points of damage")
                else:
                    attack = bot2.strength - bot1.strength
                    bot1.lifepoints -= bot2.doDamage(attack)
                    print("Bot 1 takes",bot2.doDamage(attack),"points of damage")
                
                print("Bot 1 life points: ",bot1.lifepoints)
                print("Bot 2 life points: ",bot2.lifepoints)

                count += 1
                
                
            choice = input("Bot 2 it's your turn, press 'h' to Hit or 'q' to Quit: ")
                    
            if choice == 'h':
                print("Bot 1's strength: ",bot1.getStrength())
                print("Bot 2's strength: ",bot2.getStrength())

                if bot1.strength > bot2.strength:
                    attack = bot1.strength - bot2.strength
                    bot2.lifepoints -= bot1.doDamage(attack)
                    print("Bot 2 takes", bot1.doDamage(attack),"points of damage")
                else:
                    attack = bot2.strength - bot1.strength
                    bot1.lifepoints -= bot2.doDamage(attack)
                    print("Bot 1 takes",bot2.doDamage(attack),"points of damage")
                    
                print("Bot 1 life points: ",bot1.lifepoints, "Bot 2 life points: ",bot2.lifepoints)
                
                    
                    
            if bot1.lifepoints > bot2.lifepoints:
                    print("Bot 1 Wins this round!",'\n',"Thanks for playing!",'\n',"Goodbye!")
                    break
            if bot1.lifepoints == bot2.lifepoints:
                    print("It's a tie :,(")
                    break
            if bot2.lifepoints > bot1.lifepoints:
                print("Bot 2 Wins this round!",'\n',"Thanks for playing!",'\n',"Goodbye!")
                break
            count += 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).